# pandas Dataframe set value fails

Tags: python, pandas

I been following the documentation but it keeps on throwing this error

```
row_names = ["ab_" + str(x) for x in range(4)]
col_names = ["n_" + str(x) for x in range(5)]

df = pd.DataFrame(index=row_names, columns=col_names)
df = df.fillna(0) # with 0s rather than NaNs
# Load the images 
print df.loc['ab_3','n_1']
df.set_value['ab_3','n_1', '1']
print df
```

Error:

```
TypeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using wrong type of brackets, you want `()` not `[]`:

```
df.set_value('ab_3','n_1', '1')

      n_0  n_1  n_2  n_3  n_4
ab_0    0    0    0    0    0
ab_1    0    0    0    0    0
ab_2    0    0    0    0    0
ab_3    0    1    0    0    0
```

Answer (score 1):

Unlike `loc`, `set_value` is a method, so it needs to be called.

But `df.set_value(['ab_3','n_1', '1'])` won't do what you expect as well.
See the its [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_value.html).